# Python 3.4 code help - I can't make this work

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, converters, currency

I am new to python. This is my code:

```
print("Welcome to the Currency Converter")

print("This Currency Converter converts: ")

print(" US [D]ollar")

print(" [E]uro")

print(" British[P]ound Sterling")

print(" Japanese[Y]en")

print()

def input1() :

    a = input("Enter the currency inital {eg. [E] for Euro} you wish to convert from: ")
    if a.lower is not ('e','y','p','d'):
        print("That is not a valid currency inital. Please try again ")
        input1()
input1()

def input2() :

    b = input("Enter the currency inital you wish to convert to: ")
    if b.lower is not ('e','y','p','d'):
        print("That is not a valid currency inital. Please try again")
        input2()
input2()
```

It's always repeating even though I don't want it to. My aim is to make it work only if `e`,`y`,`d` or `p` is entered, otherwise it should display the error message and repeat the question.

Comment: You probably want `not in (...)`

Comment: Please read Python documentation on [`while` loops.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming)

Comment: `a.lower` is a function, you have to call it: `a.lower()`, and you are missing an `in` keyword.

Comment: I really miss the "lacks minimal understanding" close reason :/

Comment: @vaultah there really are worse questions than this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't properly call the functions nor does it assign global variables for conversion. In addition, you shouldn't use the `is` keyword, which checks for equivalent references in memory, you should use the `in` keyword which checks for the existence of an element in your tuple.

```
print("Welcome to the Currency Converter")

print("This Currency Converter converts: ")

print(" US [D]ollar")

print(" [E]uro")

print(" British[P]ound Sterling")

print(" Japanese[Y]en")

print()

def input1() :

    a = input("Enter the currency inital {eg. [E] for Euro} you wish to convert from: ")
    if a.lower() not in ('e','y','p','d'):
        print("That is not a valid currency inital. Please try again ")
        return input1()
    return a

a = input1()

def input2() :

    b = input("Enter the currency inital you wish to convert to: ")
    if b.lower() not in ('e','y','p','d'):
        print("That is not a valid currency inital. Please try again")
        return input2()
    return b

b = input2()
```

Comment: Yeah guys, sorry I forgot about fixing `in`.

Comment: What's wrong with it now?

Comment: Did you check the return value of the functions when you enter a wrong letter in the fjrst attempt?

Comment: How's this Jasper, recursion?

Comment: Better :-)  I'd still rather use a loop instead of recursion here, but that's just a matter of taste

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems:

You are reading the input in a function, but never returning it.

```
def fun():
  a = 1

fun()
print(a)  # NameError
```

Your test fails, because you are comparing a method (`a.lower`) with a tuple. You have to call the function and check wether the result is `in` a sequence type:

```
if a.lower() not in ('e', 'y', 'p', 'd'):
  ...
```

Finally, there's no need to call the `input1` function recursively:

```
def input1() :
  while True:    
    a = input("Enter the currency inital {eg. [E] for Euro} you wish to convert from: ")
    if a.lower() not in ('e','y','p','d'):
      print("That is not a valid currency inital. Please try again ")
    else:
      return a.lower()
```

and then in the "main" part of the script:

```
from_curr = input1()
```

(don't use `from` as variable name, since it is a [keyword](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords)).

Answer (score 0):

1. `a.lower` is a function which you need to call, otherwise you only get a function reference back. So do `a.lower()`.
2. `if x is not ('e', 'y', 'p', 'd')` – The `is` (or `is not`) operator checks for *identity*. On the left side you have the user input, and on the right side, you have a 4-element tuple with possible characters. Those two will never have the same identity. You want to use the `in` operator:

   ```
   if a.lower() not in ('e', 'y', 'p', 'd'):
       …
   ```